# Passing a string from one html to another

Tags: javascript, html, string, local-storage

I am trying to pass a string value from one html to another via window.localstorage but it doesnt seem to work, here's my code:

There's a button on index.html:

```
<a href="./comer.html" onclick="passString("whatever")">
```

the function:

```
function passString(optionch){
    window.localStorage.setItem("option", "optionch");
}
```

then in another html I try to take that string:

```
<body onload="pruebaString()">
<ul>
 ....
<li id="testString">
```

the function:

```
function pruebaString(){
    document.getElementById("testString").innerHTML =
        window.localStorage.getItem("option");
}
```

but the `li` doesn't display nothing, and I don't get any error on chrome console.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `onclick="passString("whatever")"` will cause problems use single quotes instead: `onclick="passString('whatever')"`.

Comment: @jimjimmy1995, post that as answer, it may be correct

Answer (score 4):

The line `onclick="passString("whatever")"` will cause problems use single quotes instead: `onclick="passString('whatever')"`.

Also `.setItem("option", "optionch");` should be `.setItem("option", optionch);` as you are passing the variable optionch not the string optionch.

Edit: The page may also be redirected before your script has chance to execute. Try something like this:

**HTML**

```
<a href="#" onclick="passString('whatever')">
```

**JS**

```
function passString(optionch){
    window.localStorage.setItem("option", optionch);
    window.location.href = '**[pageyounavigateto]**';
}
```